# How to take a screenshot of a KDE Splash screen?

Tags: screenshot, plasma5, bootsplash

I would like to take a screenshot of the KDE Plasma 5 splash screen as I am creating a new splash theme. But pressing <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> during the splash doesn't launch spectacle (my screenshooter) until after the splash screen is gone and the screenshot it takes is of the desktop as it appears *after* the splash screen.

Comment: The only way I can think of is to run a virtual machine and take a screenshot of its splash screen, but not sure if that really suits your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Use scrot:

```
DISPLAY=:0 scrot screenshot.png
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to launch KDE/plasma splash screens in test mode and easily capture a screenshot with your favorite screenshot tool, like this.

```
ksplashqml --test <path-to-theme-directory>
```

Personally, I always prefer to start it inside a nested X server using `Xephyr`, and then using `scrot` for the screen grab. This way I can easily control the screenshot size and DPI. This is especially useful when running with multiple screens with mixed DPI and dimensions, as running `ksplashqml` will try to display one fullscreen window on each and every screen you have.

```
Xephyr -br -ac -screen 1920x1080+960+540 :1 &
QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1 DISPLAY=:1 ksplashqml --test $XDG_DATA_HOME/plasma/look-and-feel/my.personal.theme/ &
scrot -u -d 2 -o $XDG_DATA_HOME/plasma/look-and-feel/my.personal.theme/contents/previews/splash.png
```

**Xephyr**

- `-br` create root window with black background
- `-ac` disable access control restrictions
- `-screen <GEOMETRY>` Show window at given geometry. I like to display it as a 1920x1080 window, centered on my leftmost 3840x2160 screen, which turns out to 1920x1080+960+540. The format is standard X Geometry, so you can specify anything from window size (WxH) to position, bit depth, rotation and fps.
- `:1` The Display. `:0` is usually your primary X Display. If you start multiple Xephyr, you can start them at `:2`, `:3`, etc.
- `&` run in background

**ksplashqml**

- `QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1` Qt Scale Factor for HiDPI. In this case, I want to emulate an 1920x1080 Lowdpi screen. Try to experiment yourself with 1.43, 1.5, 0.5, 2 or different scale factors to see how your splash screen would behave in different real world scenarios. **Tip**: You might want to use a slightly larger scale factor for your screenshot, such as 1.25 instead of 1, to give your splash screen a slightly zoomed-in feel. This greatly helps users with recognizing your splash screen when the screenshot is later on displayed at a 300x200 size on a 4K monitor...
- `DISPLAY=:1` The DISPLAY that you started Xephyr at
- `--test` launch your splash screen in test mode
- `PATH` The directory of your theme containing the metadata.desktop file. I like to put all my splash screens inside `$XDG_DATA_HOME`, which is usually `~/.local/share/`. Plasma will automatically search and detect splash screens in `plasma/look-and-feel` in both `/usr/share` and `$XDG_DATA_HOME`. This way, I can easily choose my local splash screens in my normal plasma settings (either directly in the config file or through the systemsettings app), without root acces or modifying my `/usr` partition.
- `&` run in background

**scrot**

- `-u` take screenshot of focused window
- `-d <n>` delay screenshot by *n* seconds, this gives you time to switch to your window
- `-o` force file to overwrite previous file
- `PATH` path where you want to save your screen shot

**SDDM Theme Bonus**

Using this approach, you can then do the same with a matching *sddm theme*, which is often desired, like this:

```
QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1.5 DISPLAY=:1 sddm-greeter --test-mode <PATH> &
```

Where PATH is the path to the directoy containing the sddm theme, e.g. /usr/share/sddm/themes/breeze